# attempting to download a pip file in command prompt

Tags: python, windows, pip, command-prompt

I am attempting to download a pip file through the windows command prompt. I am using command prompt as admin and have followed all instructions online but I keep getting errors either:

The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
[image]
when in the local disk(C:) or

The system cannot find the path specified.
[image]

When moved outside of the (C:) local disk.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I just need this pip file downloaded.

Comment: `~` is expanded to home directory by *nix shells like bash. It's not for Windows CMD.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Afaik, windows doesn't accept a "~" in the command cd.

If you have a relative path just use a "." instead.

Btw, you don't need a "/" before a "C:"